# Replace real newlines with \n in text file

Tags: linux, replace, raspberry-pi

On a Pi, in a text file like this

```
line1
line2
line3
...
```

how can I translate that to a file with just one line formatted like this

```
line1\n\line2\nline3\n......
```

NB The real file is 50MB and 200000 lines long

Comment: Well, I've read that other question and I can't see an answer to my question but ce la vie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`

`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' my.txt >> new_my.txt`
This will read the whole file in a loop, then replaces the newline(s) with a "\n" and store it in a new file.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed you can:

```
sed -z -i -e 's/\n/\\n/g' file
```

replace all newlines for `\n` character. This can use some memory, as it can read the whole file into memory.

With `awk` you can print each line with `\\n` on the end:

```
awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}'
```

You can use `xargs` to split the input on newlines and run `printf`:

```
cat file | xargs -d $'\n' printf '%s\\n'
```